# I would like to get an image from JAR library to my project in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

```xml
<Button text="CLICK ME" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
       <graphic>
           <ImageView>
               <Image url="@/toolbarButtonGraphics/general/TipOfTheDay16.gif"/>
           </ImageView>
       </graphic>
</Button>
```

Here is my javaFX code to print an icon with a button but it gives me a Error like:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users\sanjay\IdeaProjects\Layouts2\jlfgr-1_0.jar
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jlfgr.1.0: Invalid module name: '1' is not a Java identifier
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Remove the underscore in the name of your jar. This is not allowed inside a version number.

Comment: @mipa hmm .. isn't it more that numeric as first char in a name is generally not allowed (no matter if modules, packages, classes ...)?

Comment: Open the jar file as a zip file, edit META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, and add this line: `Automatic-Module-Name: jlfgr`

Comment: @kleopatra As far as I can see this package name results in an illegal module name. It can be cured by either renaming the package or as VGR has suggested by specifying an explicit module name in the manifest. I had a similar issue some time ago with a Maven dependency on which I did not have any influence. I was lucky though because the author of that module was cooperative. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do 2 things in order to get your image answer correct..
I have faced the same problem, here is what I did:

1. change the name of your jar directory from jlfgr_1.0 to jlfgr
2. If your using IntelliJ IDEA, right click on the project name and select open module settings..
3. Then go to modules and select dependencies..
4. Then you can select the plus (+) button and then select jar or directories..
5. Click on classes and then navigate to the section where your jar is stored. Then you can click on ok
6. Your jar file must appear in the external libraries section.
7. Now comes the most important part. Go to your module.info java module and then type "requires jlfgr;"
8. Then your code will work.